# Do most built-in Python classes lack __dict__? What are the reasons?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-internals

Is it a general rule that native Python classes, e.g. `os.stat_result`, have no `__dict__` attribute (as for instance suggested in [how to avoid class having a __dict__](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29572421/1711186))?

What are the technical reasons why built-in classes (e.g. `os.stat_result`) lack this feature?

Comment: Even if they had a `__dict__`, their data wouldn't be in it. Data in a dict is really slow and inconvenient to access from C.

Comment: @user2357112. You suggest **C** and performance reasons are for this? Do I understand the comment correclty as a partial answer that python3 being itself build from **C** would cause the lack of `__dict__` on some/many/all builtin classes' instances?

Comment: `os.stat_result.__dict__['n_fields']`
`Out[115]: 22` Seems to me it does have `__dict__` attribute? Am I missing something?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry also likely is that *I* am missting something and you are correct. However the presence of __dict__ should as was indicated in other questions allow the desired behaviour of `json.dumbs(<class instance with __dict__>)` to become a `{"attr":value, "attr2":value2....}` is that not so?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry. Wha is the `Out[115]: 22` reference/info?

Comment: @cosmic_inquiry: You're looking at a different object. That's the `os.stat_result` type, not an instance of the type (as would be returned by `os.stat`). `os.stat_result` itself has a `__dict__`, as do all types (barring a weird metaclass hiding the attribute or something, in which case the underlying dict itself would still be there), but instances of the type have no `__dict__`.

Comment: @user2357112, updated the question to reference to another question, which kind of refers to *performance issues* seemingly being the reason (as suggested by you also?) that built-in class instances lacking `__dict__`.

Comment: For why, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1529099/3001761. For, perhaps more usefully to you, how you can proceed with getting the attributes anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411028/python-printing-attributes-with-no-dict

Comment: Yeah, I understand the question now. I think that ^ answers it. Learned something new today.

Comment: Per jonrsharpe, possible duplicate of [Can't set attributes of object class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1529002/cant-set-attributes-of-object-class) (albeit phrased rather differently)

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if there is a "correct" answer for this - the reasoning is that for most of these objects one can happily live without attaching extra-attributes to their instances - and the cost of having a `__dict__` is simply not worth it.

Can you try imagining if Python's `int`s had `__dict__`s? For every number, beside the 80-something bytes it takes, another 200-ish byte object would be built, so that one could have attributes to pegged to their "42"?

Also, for imutable classes, like tuples, strings, and such, the same instance can be reused in different contexts - a `__dict__` in one instance could make a seemingly non-connected instance of the same object to suddenly spawn attributes.

Also, the specific class you mention `os.stat_result` is a named-tuple - it is meant to be immutable and compact.

So, besides the size and resource cost of creating `__dict__` for most objects, there is also the coding issue: these are usually natively coded (i.e. written in C) - and th e `__dict__` attribute would have to be explicitly created - so unlike classes coded in Python - one have to go out of his way to allow `__dict__` in these classes, while for Python code, the detour is on avoiding `__dict__`.

And finally, when the community developing the language concludes that there would be any clear advantage in an object having a `__dict__`, it might be included. That happened with the Function object type itself a while ago - and functions now can have attributes attached to them by decorators, and this can be put to good use.

While if you need code attaching extra-attributes to a single class, you can do it the old-fashion way, and just inherit that class and convert your object to it. (I jut found out that `os.stat_result` is *not* a named_tuple, and can't be used as a base class - sorry for that - so, wrapping it in a simple class might be the simplest thing to do:

```
class MyStatResult:
    def __init__(self, stat_result):
         self.stat = stat_result

    def __repr__(self):
         return "Wrapper for" + repr(self.stat)
```

Now, if your goal is to extract the fields titles/values as a dict, and not adding extra attributes to it - the introspectable part of these objects is given by `dir` - in the case of `os.stat_result` the fieds that matter have a nice prefix:

```
stat = os.stat(path)

stat_dict = lambda path: {name: getattr(stat, field)  for field in dir(stat) if field.startswith("st_")}
```

In Python 3.8, thanks to PEP 572, one will be able to write that as a nice oneliner:

```
stat_dict = lambda path: {name: getattr(stat, field)  for field in dir(stat:=os.stat(path)) if field.startswith("st_")}
```